# Compiler warning for seq in build.sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

Working on bringing up a Lift 3 application, and the `build.sbt` file has the following line:

```
seq(lessSettings:_*)
```

There are several instances of lower-case `seq` in the build file, and they are all crossed-out and come with the compiler warning:

> In build.sbt files, this call can be removed.  In other cases, this can usually be replaced by Seq.

The source for `seq` reads (predictably):

```
@scala.deprecated("In build.sbt files, this call can be removed.  In other cases, this can usually be replaced by Seq.")
def seq(settings : sbt.Def.Setting[_]*) : sbt.Def.SettingsDefinition = { /* compiled code */ }
```

What I can't determine is what to do if I want to 'update' this function call. Simply converting the above-example to:

```
lessSettings:_*
```

...will fail. I'm not sure if the deprecation message means that line can just be removed? That seems unlikely, though I must admit ignorance to the specifics of what is going on here. What did `seq` used to do? Why is it no longer needed? What should one do to replace it and remove the compiler warning?

Answer (score 1):

You should also remove the `:_*`, so that your line becomes:

```
lessSettings
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain why those two formulations are equivalent?